# how to call functions/objects from another process

Tags: python, flask, discord.py, flask-socketio

## Summarize the problem

---

I have a flask server (with endpoints and socket events) and a discord bot, both work independently, I want to run them on parallel so I can trigger functions of the bot from a flask endpoint.

## Describe what you have tried

---

For context, this is an example of the endpoint:

````py
@app.route("/submit", methods=["POST"])
async def submit():
    data = request.json
    userid = int(os.getenv("USER_ID"))
    message = f"```Title: {data['title']}\nMessage: {data['message']}```"
    await send_dm(userid, message)
    return data
````

Where `send_dm` in its own package looks like this

```py
# notice that this is not a method of a function
# nor a decorated function with properties from the discord library
# it just uses an intance of the commands.Bot class
async def send_dm(userid: int, message: str):
    user = await bot.fetch_user(userid)
    channel = await user.create_dm()
    await channel.send(message)
```

So to run them on parallel **and be able to communicate them with each other** I tried:

##### Attempt 1: multiprocessing module

```py
def main():
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(2)
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

    loop.run_in_executor(executor, start_bot)
    loop.run_in_executor(executor, start_server)

    loop.run_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

When the function on the endpoint mentioned executes I get the following error `AttributeError: '_MissingSentinel' object has no attribute 'is_set' on concurrent tasks`

##### Attempt 2: threading module

```py
# make them aware of each other
bot.flask_app = app
app.bot = bot
async def main():
    task = threading.Thread(target=start_bot)
    task.start()
    start_server()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

This approach brings two issues:

- First is that to run `start_bot` I use `.start()` method instead of `.run()` because according to the [this example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/advanced_startup.py) `.run()` created its own event pool which would make it unreachable by other processes, and `.start()` is an async function, so when running this I get the error: `RuntimeError: You cannot use AsyncToSync in the same thread as an async event loop - just await the async function directly.`
- Second is that even using the `run.()` function then the same issue arises when executing mentioned endpoint.

##### Attempt 3: asyncio module

```py
def main():
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(2)
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    boo = loop.run_in_executor(executor, start_bot)
    baa = loop.run_in_executor(executor, start_server)

    loop.run_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This time I actually get the execute both processes but still cannot call the function I want from the flask endpoint.

I also tried

```
await asyncio.gather([start_server(), start_bot()])
```

But same issue as Attempt 2, and I already upgraded the flask[async] module so that is not the issue anymore.

## Show some code

---

To reproduce what I have right now you can either check the full repo [here](https://github.com/carepollo/assistant) that has only 4 files **or** this sample should be enough to reproduce.

```py
from server import socketio, app
from bot import bot
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import asyncio
import threading

env_path = os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/.env"
load_dotenv(env_path)

def start_server():
    socketio.run(app)

def start_bot():
    token = os.getenv("BOT_TOKEN")
    bot.run(token)

async def main():
    # this doesn't achieve what I want and is the main part of the problem
    start_server()
    start_bot()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Program exited")
```

Did I miss something?, point it out in the comments and I will add it in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is what `IPC` was invented for. There's a dpy helper library that you can use: https://github.com/MiroslavRosenov/better-ipc

Both processes have nothing to do with each other, so you should launch them separately instead of hacking it together in one main.